Application of the Jensen's inequality
For a convex function $\phi(x)$, Jensen's inequality states:
\begin{equation}
E_{x}(\phi(x)) \geq \phi(E_{x}(X)) 
\end{equation}
where $E_x$ is the expectation. When applying the Jensen's inequality to the following expression
\begin{equation}
\left(E_{z} \left \{E_{y|z} \left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{r}(x|y,z)\,dx\right\}\right\}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}} 
\end{equation}
assuming $0<r<1$ the function $\frac{1}{1-r} >1$ so
\begin{equation}
\left(E_{z} \left \{E_{y|z} \left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{r}(x|y,z)\,dx\right\}\right\}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}}  \leq
 E_{z} \left\{ \left(E_{y|z} \left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{r}(x|y,z)\,dx\right\}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}}\right\}
\end{equation}
I think the result should be just the opposite (i.e. $\leq$ should be replaced by $\geq$), but I don't understand why. Could you please help me?
When looking at the expression above we realize that
\begin{equation}
E_{z} \left\{ \left(E_{y|z} \left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{r}(x|y,z)\,dx\right\}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}}\right\} =\mathcal{E}_{r}(X|Y,Z)
\end{equation}
So if the relation I wrote is correct
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{r}(X|Y,Z) \geq \left(E_{z} \left \{E_{y|z} \left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{r}(x|y,z)\,dx\right\}\right\}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}} = \left(E_{z} \left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{r}(x|z)\,dx\right\}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}}
\end{equation}
By applying the Jensen's inequality to the rhs we have
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{r}(X|Z) = E_{z} \left \{\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{r}(x|z)\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}} \right \} \geq
\left(E_{z} \left \{ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{r}(x|z)\,dx\right\}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}}
\end{equation}
I expect to get
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{r}(X|Y,Z) \leq \mathcal{E}_{r}(X|Z)
\end{equation}
which is possible only if the sign is reversed.As a matter of fact conditioning on more variables (Y and Z) can only reduce the entropy compared to conditioning on fewer variables (only Z).

Why do you think it should be ?

I added the explanation

I think you are looking at the wrong function.
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_r(X|Z) = E_Z \left\{ \left( \int_\mathbb{R} f^r(x|z) \, dx \right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}} \right\} =
E_Z \left\{ \left( \int_\mathbb{R}
\left( E_{Y|Z} \left[ f(x|y,z) \right] \right)^r
\, dx \right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}} \right\}.
\end{equation}
Assuming $0<r<1$ the function $\phi(x) = x^r$ is concave, so
\begin{equation}
\left( E_{Y|Z} \left[ f(x|y,z) \right] \right)^r \ge 
E_{Y|Z} \left[ f^r(x|y,z) \right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_r(X|Z) \ge E_Z \left\{ \left( \int_\mathbb{R}
E_{Y|Z} \left[ f^r(x|y,z) \right]
\, dx \right)^{\frac{1}{1-r}} \right\}
= \mathcal{E}_r(X|Y,Z).
\end{equation}
